# How to get the details of User(Computer)name and the Password?

Tags: password, password-recovery, privacy, username, passwd-file

Where the details of Password and Username/Computer Name being Stored  in Ubuntu 14.04?

How to Change the Password and the Username?

Ways to recover the forgotten Password and the Username without doing any Harm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usernames are stored in `/etc/passwd` - so you can look in here to remind yourself what the usernames are - anyone can read this file.

Passwords are stored (hashed) in `/etc/shadow`

To reset a user's password:

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

-- it will ask you for a new password.

Last question - erm - don't tell anyone?  Not quite sure what sort of suggestion you're looking for here.

If you can't get into the machine at all (so can't look in `/etc/passwd`) then you have to reset the root password, with which [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=ubuntu%20reset%20root%20password) can help.

Comment: But i can't able to see any name in '/etc/passwd'. I think it stores the log? @Mark Smith

Comment: Since the Password being Hashed. How to View the Password @Mark Smith

Comment: Usernames are in `/etc/passwd` - definitely.  The first item in every row - for example yours might say `sridhar:x:<more stuff>`.  You cannot recover the original password from the hash - that would be terrible.  The best you can do is create a new one for that account.

Comment: Good stuff.  You're welcome!